# Razor web pages default page

Tags: asp.net, razor

How do I change the default.cshtml to mypage.cshtml in razor web pages? (Not Razor views with MVC)

It doesn't work if I change the default document in IIS.

What is the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the web.config as you may need to clear/remove the default.cshtml from being the default document.